# Was removed vs has been removed

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

I am not a native speaker and would like to know the difference between these two:

*1. Profile was removed*

*2. Profile has been removed*

Yes I know it is Past Simple vs Present Perfetc. For me, the second one is better because there is a consequence but in some cases also first one is used. Why?

Comment: Need the context!

Answer (score 2):

"was removed" refers to something in the past. "has been removed" is presented as information about an event supposed to be new for the reader. It is perfect for news.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is the simple past passive.  The second is the present perfect passive.  The both indicate an action happened but not who did the action.  This grammar is often used for these kinds of things, as it's not really important who did the removing but that the action happened.

I would choose the second option.  My reason is that the present perfect is used when an action in the past has relevance for the present and for future decisions.  If your profile has been removed, this will certainly affect your user experience and will also affect your future.

Answer (score -1):

The first sound like a robot, very consice.
The second sounds more human. Who has been removed? the profile. okay.

Comment: I disagree. The 1st one sounds like *someone* did the removing; the 2nd, the *system* did the removing -I can't say why exactly, though...